# Recursion in C only works when printing unrelated things

Tags: c, recursion, printf, fibonacci

I've just started learning C, and I decided to work on some of the [Euler Problems](https://projecteuler.net/) for practice. 
The program that isn't working is meant to solve Problem2, which asks to compute the sum of all even Fibonacci numbers below 4,000,000.

What's really weird about this program is that it actually works, but only if I print something during recursion: whenever I try commenting out the `printf("bazooka");` line in the recursive function, I get results that seem completely random, and vary between large positive numbers and large negative numbers (eg  -882154758 and 770491113) upon successive executions of the same program.
On the other hand, if I print something, no matter what, in the recursive function, I get the correct output.

I find this behavior extremely weird and interesting, and I would really like to know what's going on: what really puzzles me is that the outputted number changes even when the program is not altered at all. Also, I don't understand why printing during recursion should have any effect on the integer computations being performed.

This is my main function:

```
int first = 1; int second = 2; int total = 0;
total = Fibo(first,second, total);
printf("\nthis is my result for Euler 2: ");
printf("%d",total);
```

And this is my recursive function:

```
  int Fibo(int first, int second, int total) {
  printf("bazooka");
  if (second < 4000000) {
    int add;
    second = first+second;
    first = second-first;
    if (first%2 == 0) {
      add = first;
    }
      total = add+Fibo(first,second,total);
  }
  return total;
}
```

Can anybody help me figure this out? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You need to initialize `int add = 0;`. Otherwise it can (and apparently does) take whatever value happens to be written in the location where it is stored in the line `total = add+Fibo(first,second,total);`

Comment: Even with your `bazooka` fix, I get `-1900183196`. Surely that is wrong.

Comment: A recursive function is complete over-kill. Save that technique for the more difficult questions. One simple loop will do it. As the limit is 4000000 `int` is adequate with 32-bit machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot @UnholySheep! I thought that the add variable would be newly initialized to 0 every time the recursive function was called, but apparently that's not the case. I'm still puzzled by the fact that printing something resolved the problem. Does anybody know why that happens?

Comment: @andy_programs as Rad Lexus pointed out, it doesn't really solve it (at least not in a reliable manner) - it may just have been a side-effect on your particular system where the call to `printf` changed values in the memory location which was later occupied by `add`. There is no guarantee for that behavior though

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks for the input but that's pretty unrelated to my question. The purpose of this program for me is not only to solve the problems but, more importantly, to learn as much C syntax quickly. Recursion seemed like a fun way to learn about function calling and the like.

Comment: No it isn't, it suggests that you dump your solution and start over, since programming is about finding the simplest solution. Build your skill with the difficulty of the questions, not make them more complicated than they are.

Comment: @UnholySheep that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

`add` is not initialized if `first` is odd. Make sure to initialize the variable in both cases and the bug will go away.

Now, for explaining the observed behavior: using an uninitialized variable can show as a random "value" or it can cause the program to malfunction in other random ways. (The technical term in C-like languages is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).) In your case it is likely that the value was a garbage left over from the previous usage of the memory location used for the stack frame of the function, or the previous value of the register. A call to `printf` can appear to fix things because its implementation happens to use and clear the relevant portion of the memory. Needless to say, this is not something you can depend on.

Note that this kind of bug will be diagnosed by the compiler with the appropriate warning settings, such as `-Wall` for GCC or Clang.

Answer (score -3):

Well, I cannot relate 100% about that behavior, but for sure when you get numbers like the negative number, is because you are exceeding the max value of the `int` value:

```
INT_MIN = -2147483648 
INT_MAX = +2147483647
```

Change this type to `long`, or `long long` if getting the same result.

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) you can check the data type boundaries.

Comment: This was a fair guess, but as you can see by the other answer, it's not the cause here. A good way to check if this is the problem is to actually print out the intermediate values; doing so shows it never reaches that high.

Comment: As it happens, `int` is adequate for the [problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=2).

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, it seems the values presented in your link are strange and not very representative. One of the reasons why I prefer [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) over cplusplus.com - the information there is usually more accurate. (Also `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` are not actually constants, they depend on the compiler)